# spring-ws jdom wrong response

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws, jdom, jdom-2

I'm struggling with Spring-WS, used with JDOM.

Code:

```
    @Endpoint
    @Namespace(uri = "http://example.pl/gb/schemas", prefix = "gb")
    public class PdfCheckStatusEndPoint {
        private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://example.pl/gb/schemas";

        ...    


        @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "PdfStatusRequest")
        @Namespace(uri = NAMESPACE_URI, prefix = "sch")
        @ResponsePayload
        public Element getPdfStatus(@XPathParam("//sch:policyNr") String policyNr) {

              org.jdom2.Namespace javaxml2Namespace = org.jdom2.Namespace.getNamespace("http://example.pl/gb/schemas");
              Element responseElement = new Element("PersonResponse", javaxml2Namespace);
              Element childElement1 = new Element("FullName");
              childElement1.setText("john doe");

              Element childElement2 = new Element("SSN");
              childElement2.setText("12345");

              responseElement.addContent(childElement1);
              responseElement.addContent(childElement2);
              return responseElement;
        }
    }
```

The endpoint works itself, but the response is other than expected:

```
  <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <env:Header/>
     <env:Body>
        <PersonResponse xmlns="http://example.pl/gb/schemas"/>
     </env:Body>
  </env:Envelope>
```

As you can see, no children are returned, just the root element. Any ideas?

Comment: The code you have above looks fine... there is something else happening outside the method. can you debug that method at the return-statement? and then follow the XML back up to where it is output?

Comment: Second comment, Are the childElements supposed to be in the NO-namespace, or the namespace `http://example.pl/gb/schemas`

Comment: thanks for your input, I provided the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like adding this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

along with bean definition:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="messageFactory">
        <bean class="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

does the work.